# Trouble With Package "ade4"

Tags: r

Hello I've been trying to use the library package "adegenet" and while the package seems to be installed when I try to run the library("adegenet") I get an error message telling me that some problem has occured with ade4. Here is the code up to the error message:

```
Package ‘adegenet’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\esteb\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGm98iy\downloaded_packages
> library("adegenet")
Loading required package: ade4
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ade4’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required
Error: package ‘ade4’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘adegenet’ was built under R version 3.6.3 
2: package ‘ade4’ was built under R version 3.6.3
```

I couldn't quite find anything online to explain what's going on here. Any help appreciated

Comment: Did you ever install ade4?

Comment: I just tried installing it by itself and keep getting the same error even after it told me ade4 had successfully been installed.

Comment: Apparently, the problem is that an old version of the package vctrs is being loaded. Try to install this package on its own (it's a CRAN package, so you just need to use install.packages) and the try again.

Comment: It's always a good idea to use `dependencies=TRUE` when installing packages.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. Updating RStudio and R itself, which prompted updating all my previously installed packages fixed the issue. I tried the dependencies=TRUE before with both "ade4" and adegenet" and it didn't work if anyone in the future ever runs into this problem.